# Enviar formulário sem usar PHP ou Similares

Tags: html5, twitter-bootstrap, formulário

Preciso que meu FORM em HTML com Bootstrap seja enviado.
O problema é que não sei nada de PHP. A funcionalidade que preciso é o envio de mensagem para um endereço de e-mail. Apenas os dados e uma mensagem que o cliente queira enviar. Não vai para nenhum BD nem será usado em outro Form. Uma página de contato tradicional.

Existe alguma maneira que eu possa enviar meu FORM, sem precisar usar uma linguagem dinâmica?

Comment: Podes explicar o que queres fazer com o form? ou seja, qual é a utilização que pretendes dar aos dados do formulário?

Comment: Pra enviar o formulário você pode usar só *HTML* mesmo, mas pra processar os dados enviados você vai precisar de alguma linguagem de programação.

Comment: Parafraseando o que o @Sergio disse: Pra onde você quer enviar o formulário?

Comment: Dependendo de o que quiser fazer é possível utilizar algo como o http://jotformz.com, aí vc cria e define um layout para o formulário e ele mesmo armazena e envia os dados pra você por email

Comment: A única forma que conheço é usando um <b>mailto<b> como action, onde o formulário vai para o endereço de email do parâmetro. Veja que forms precisam de actions para fazerem sentido. Pode ser uma simples função javascript, que mostra um alerta, enfim... Concordo com o @Sergio, a pergunta não está clara.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para enviar um formulário de e-mail apenas com alguma linguagem de programação. Em PHP é bem simples, procure pela função mail();

Segue um exemplo:

```
   <?php

       $para = "seu-email@dominio.com.br"; 

       $nome = $_POST['ID_CAMPO_HTML_NOME']; //valor digitado no campo Nome
       $assunto = $_POST['ID_CAMPO_HTML_ASSUNTO']; //valor digitado no campo Assunto
       $mensagem = "<strong>Nome: </strong>".$nome; 
       $mensagem .= "<br> <strong>Mensagem:  
       </strong>".$_POST['ID_CAMPO_HTML_MENSAGEM']; //valor digitado no campo Mensagem


    //CODIFICAÇÕES CORRETAS PARA O FORMATO DO E-MAIL
       $headers = "Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
       $headers .= "From: dominio.com.br<sistema@dominio.com.br>\n"; 
       $headers .= "X-Sender: <sistema@dominio.com.br>\n";
       $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion()."\n"; 
       $headers .= "X-IP: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n";
       $headers .= "Return-Path: <sistema@dominio.com.br>\n"; 
       $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";

    mail($para, $assunto, $mensagem, $headers); 

    ?>
```

Use o "action" do form, referenciando para o código PHP

```
<form action="enviaEmail.php"> ...
```

Comment: Maurício, obrigado pela sua resposta e ajuda.
Mas o PHP ainda é um bicho papão pra mim.
Sei que é a linguagem mais indicada, mas ainda não me sinto confortável em usá-la. De qualquer forma, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Disponha! Mas acredito que só é possivel o envio de e-mail através de alguma linguagem, de qualquer forma ficarei acompanhando o post, quem sabe alguém não dá uma solução mais acessivel...

Comment: Angelo, só o tempo que vc gastou aqui dizendo que tem "medo do php", se vc tivesse usado esse tempo para tentar ler e entender scripts php de 2 linhas de código, já teria resolvido em 10 minutos ou 4 horas..  Sem querer ofender, mas acho que precisa ouvir uma dessa para sair desse "eu não sei, eu tenho medo, eu...".. entendeu? espero que uma crítica assim possa te dar um empurrão.. pra frente né.. rsrs

Comment: Daniel, Resolvido.
Demorei um pouco, mas deu certo.
Usando o mail() que o Mauricio mandou e um dia de pesquisa, consegui por pra funcionar.
Ainda preciso acertar os detalhes, por exemplo, a mensagem está caindo no span.
Mas pelo menos, funcionou.
Muito Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Boa Angelo! Não é tão dificil, é pesquisar e entender como funciona, boa sorte. Qualquer coisa posta aí!

Answer (score 5):

Pode utilizar o [formspree](https://formspree.io/).

Não é preciso registro, nem programação *back/front-end*. Basta apenas definir alguns parâmetros no formulário:

```
<form action="https://formspree.io/meu_email@mail.com" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="mensagem">
    <input type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

O valor após `https://formspree.io/` é o email para o qual serão enviadas as informações do formulário.

A [página do projeto no GitHub](https://github.com/formspree/formspree#advanced-features) mostra alguns parâmetros de opções avançadas que podem ser incluídas no formulário, para customizar a forma como ele será submetido para o destinatário.

Um exemplo contendo um título pré-definido e um email (escolhido pelo usuário) para o qual deve ser enviada uma resposta:

```
<form action='https://formspree.io/meu_email@mail.com' method='post'>

  <!-- Título/Assunto do Email. -->
  <input type='hidden' name='_subject' value='Contato de Cliente'>

  <!-- Email de Resposta. -->
  <input type='email' name='_replyto' placeholder='Email p/ contato'>

  <!-- Mensagem que será submetida. -->
  <textarea name='mensagem'></textarea>

  <button type='submit'>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente, toda linguagem é dinâmica.

O que você provavelmente quis dizer é "linguagem que execute em server side".

Um meio simples de resolver a sua questão é utilizar "mailto" do HTML.

**Exemplo:**

```
<a href='mailto:email@de.quem.recebe?subject=Assunto&body=conteúdo'>Enviar email</a>
```

Exemplo com `<form>`

```
<FORM Action="mailto:email@para.receber.com?Subject=Assunto" METHOD="POST">
    mailto: protocol test:
    <br />Assunto 
    <INPUT name="Subject" value="Test Subject">
    <br  />Mensagem
    <TEXTAREA name="Body">
    lorem ipsum
    </TEXTAREA>
    <br />
    <INPUT type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</FORM>
```

**Desvantagem**

O usuário precisa ter um cliente de email instalado e configurado.

A grande maioria das pessoas não tem pois utilizam serviços de webmail ou messengers como facebook messenger, twitter, hotmail, yahoo, entre outros.

Para usuários Windows, por exemplo, o usuário terá provavelmente o Live Mail ou Outlook Express na tela, porém, sem configuração. 
Provavelmente vai clicar para enviar e ficará pensando que a mensagem foi mesmo enviada.
O mesmo se dá para quaisquer outros sistemas operacionais.

**Serviços de envio de formulários**

Outro meio é utilizar serviços terceiros. Há diversos serviços que fornecem uma URL para "action" do "`<form>`".

Comment: Daniel, me interessei por esse serviço de terceiros.
Como posso procurar mais a respeito? Você tem algum para indicar?
Muito Obrigado.

Comment: eu recomendo usar o próprio script fornecido pelo bootstrap..  Afinal, o motivo de querer evitar o php ou qualquer outra linguagem server side é pelo fato de vc não saber usar, certo ?  Atualmente qualquer servidor do mais básico, tem suporte php, mysql, etc.. o Bootstrap vem com um sample, um script php bem simples para envio de email no formulário de contato.. aquele formulário não é o suficiente para vc?

Comment: Daniel, seria perfeito!
Eu nem sabia que o bootstrap já vinha com um script pra isso.
Vou dar uma pesquisada pra saber mais a respeito.