# envio e-mail com bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Vi o [comentário abaixo em uma postagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/78562/enviar-formul%C3%A1rio-sem-usar-php-ou-similares#comment160794_78571), gostaria de saber se vc teria esse script para enviar e-mail pelo bootstrap, não consegui localizar no site do mesmo.

> *"eu recomendo usar o próprio script fornecido pelo bootstrap.. Afinal, o motivo de querer evitar o php ou qualquer outra linguagem server side é pelo fato de vc não saber usar, certo ? Atualmente qualquer servidor do mais básico, tem suporte php, mysql, etc.. o Bootstrap vem com um sample, um script php bem simples para envio de email no formulário de contato.. aquele formulário não é o suficiente para vc?"*

Comment: Isso não ecziste.

Comment: Danielli, bem-vinda! A tua pergunta está pouco clara. Podes explicar melhor o que procuras?

Answer (score 1):

A menos que estejamos falando de um `Backend` escrito em `NodeJS`, não é possível enviar um `E-mail` usando apenas `JavaScript`.

Caso não tenha um `Backend` para a sua pagina, talvez a solução mais simples seja utilizar alguma `API` já existente, como o [`EmailJS`](https://www.emailjs.com) ou o [`Gmail API`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/)

Caso prefira pode escrever o seu próprio Microservice na linguagem de sus preferencia, segue algumas recomendações.:

- [C# - .Net (Core) - Async WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api)
- [NodeJS - ExpressJS](https://expressjs.com)
- [Java - SparkJava](http://sparkjava.com)
- [PHP - ReactPHP](http://reactphp.org)

Para qual quer umas das escolhas acima, existem milhares de guias na internet de como se enviar um Email.

Quanto ao `Bootstrap`, você fará da mesma forma que seria sem ele, enviar uma requisição `Ajax` para o `Microservice` e deixar o servidor enviar o Email.