# Enviar lista por email

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Tenho um botão que chama essa função em jQuery.

```
sendBtn.click(function(){
    $('#dialog-confirm-send').dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: [  {   
            text: "Cancelar",
            click: function(){
                $(this).dialog('close');}
            },
            {   
            text: "Enviar",
            click: function(){
                var content = $('.cart-item');
                envia(content, email);
                content.remove();
                $('cart-content').find('.placeholder').show();
                $(this).dialog('close');
                sendBtn.fadeOut('500');
                sendText.fadeIn('500');}
            }
        ]                   
    })
    return false;
});
```

Editando: Gostaria de pegar a lista e enviar para outra função. essa outra função vai mandar pro script php via post. Não estou conseguindo pegar a lista pra mandar. Já fiz a função `envia()` e to chamando ela. ela esta executando normal, mas não leva a lista. No console diz só `object`. Abaixo a função:

```
function envia(content, email){
   alert("Eu alert!" + email);
}
```

Obrigado desde já

Comment: Front-end não pode enviar emails, exceto com protocolo `maito:`, mas ae vai depender de ter instalado um cliente de email na maquina do usuario e dele "aprovar" a ação. Se quiser isto automatico só da para fazer no back-end com SMTP (usando uma linguagem/tecnologia de servidor como C#, python, php, etc)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Enviar formulário sem usar PHP ou Similares](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/78562/enviar-formul%c3%a1rio-sem-usar-php-ou-similares)

Comment: posso usar php. essa função ta dentro de um js

Comment: ou essa função poderia mandar os dados pra outra função que mandaria os dados via ajax/post